# How to get the next HTML element after a comment by XPath?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I get the comments in an HTML document by XPath

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$comments = $xpath->query('//comment()');

foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

How can I get the next HTML element in this loop from `$comment`?

Comment: `$comment->nextSibling;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alter your XPath expression to use the `following-sibling` axis and say pick up the first node after the comment...

```
$comments = $xpath->query('//comment()/following-sibling::*[1]');
```

If you need the comment and the next node, you can first get the comment and then use XPath relative to that comment to fetch the following node...

```
$comments = $xpath->query('//comment()');
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    echo $comment->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
    $next = $xpath->query("following-sibling::*[1]", $comment)[0];
    echo $next->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I need the comment too. I want to match the HTML element to its preceding comment.

Comment: Try the update, you can also replace the `*` with any particular node type you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Element that comes next after `$comment` is its next sibling. It should be stored in `nextSibling` property:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    var_dump($comment->nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: that was my first attempt, but it returns the text element after the comment. I want to get the first HTML element.

Comment: Text element is a Node too. So you have to get sibling of sibling etc

Comment: then, I have no choice but to create a while loop to check the `nodeType` of the next element? I hope I can find an easier solution to skip the text elements to the next HTML element.

Comment: Both html and text elements are `DOMNode`s, each of them has a `nodeType`. I doubt that you can distinct one type from another in easy way.